# How to add Admob AdView in top view of ArrayAdapter

Tags: admob, android-arrayadapter, adview

i create a ArrayAdapter class to list all item in view, but i want to add a Admob Adview in top of View but not working. Pls help me.

My getView function is:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_layout, parent, false);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    TextView tv = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvNews);
    tv.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
    if(position==0){
        AdView adView = new AdView((Activity)context, AdSize.BANNER,"a152bfd02492f0b");
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        layout.addView(adView);
    }

    iv.setTag((String)items.get(position).getLink_img());
    new LoadImageAsyntask().execute(iv);
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to add admob into the adapter, add it above the list view in the parent layout.

Comment: My activity call this adapter to set view, and each row view is news_layout, i don't known set parent layout in adapter. Pls help me

Comment: But why are you trying to set it in the adapter at all? Admob is usually added to the parent activity - that's the easiest way.

Comment: I used ArrayAdapter to list all website i want read them, and i want to put only an Admob Adview on top list.

Answer (score 0):

As Szymon rightly says - do NOT try and put an AdView into an ArrayAdapter. You are just asking for pain. Rethink your application.

ArrayAdapters are for lists of similar items. The AdView should be placed above or below the ListView holding the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Ok, i understant, i should use a listview arrount listadapter and add Adview in that listview. Thank you

Comment: No. You should place the AdView either *above* or *below* the ListView.

Comment: I used a parent layout include an Adview and a ListView, and i call listview.setAdapter(adapter), so i can add admob view.

Comment: If you mean you have ParentView that contains a ListView and an AdView as siblings then yes, that is good.